# Find command with quotation marks results in "no such file"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, terminal

In my directory there are the files:

```
file1.txt  fix.log  fixRRRRRR.log  fixXXXX.log  output.txt
```

In order to understand the find command, I tried a lot of stuff among other things I wanted to use 2 wildcards. Target was to find files that start with an f and have an extension starting with an `l`.

```
$ find . f*.l*

./file1.txt
./fix.log
./fixRRRRRR.log
./output.txt
./fixXXXX.log
fix.log
fixRRRRRR.log
fixXXXX.log
```

I read in a forum answer to use quotation marks with find `find . "f*.l*"` with the result: `

```
./file1.txt
./fix.log
./fixRRRRRR.log
./output.txt
./fixXXXX.log
```

It results in `find: ‘f*.l*’: No such file or directory`

What am I doing wrong, where is my error in reasoning?

Thanks for an answer.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Maybe you want `find . -name "f*.l*" -print`? (The GNU implementation of `find` lets you leave off `-print`, but that's an extension; baseline POSIX `find` requires it).

Comment: If your goal is to understand the `find` command, I strongly suggest reading through [Using Find](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) on the Wooledge wiki (also home to the [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/) and [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide)).

Comment: Yes, I want to understand the find command. Therefore I'll follow your recommendations. Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

find doesn't work like that. In general find's call form looks like:

```
find [entry1] [entry2] ... [expressions ...]
```

Where an entry is a starting point where find starts the search for files.

In your case, you haven't actually supplied any expressions.

In the first command (without quotes), the shell expands the wildcards to a list of matching files (in the current directory), then passes the list to `find` as arguments. So `find . f*.l*` is essentially equivalent to `find . fix.log fixRRRRRR.log fixXXXX.log`. As a result, find treats all of those arguments as directories/files to search (not patterns to search for), and lists all files under `.`, (everything) then all files under `fix.log` (it's not a directory, so that's just the file itself), then all files under `fixRRRRRR.log` and finally all files under `fixXXXX.log`.

In the second one (with quotes) it searches for all files beneath the current directory (.) and tries the same for the file literally called "f*.l*".

Actually you are likely seeking for the "-name" expression, which may be used like this:

```
find . -name "f*.l*"
```

Comment: A little more explanation: in the first command (without quotes), the shell expands the wildcards to a list of matching files (in the current directory), then passes the list to `find`. So `find . f*.l*` is essentially equivalent to `find . fix.log fixRRRRRR.log fixXXXX.log`. As a result, find lists all files under `.`, (everything) then all files under `fix.log` (it's not a directory, so that's just the file itself), then all files under `fixRRRRRR.log`, then...

Comment: @GordonDavisson, thanks, added to the answer. Missed that part of question at first.

Comment: @Fat-Zer I did a minor rewrite to that section; feel free to edit/revert to your preference.

Comment: Thx a lot for your detailed information. Helped me a lot.